# Totalling an ExtJS editable grid's input fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

This question regards ExtJS 3 editable grids.  I have a need to total the input fields of one column of an editable grid.  There is [the store's sum method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum) but sometimes the data in the input fields is not necessarily in the store; for instance you might make an entry in the input field and then click a button on the toolbar.

The "traditional" way in this case seems to be to set up the appropriate listener and commit the content of the input field to the store, but this can get convoluted and seems downright unnecessary if as a result of clicking the toolbar button you will ultimately get re-directed elsewhere anyway.  Is there another solution?

Comment: You're using the row editor plugin?

Comment: No I'm not using the row editor plugin, I'm supporting an (old) ExtJS 3 editable grid.  There is no findPlugin() method in ExtJS 3

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to gather up all the input fields using the oft-overlooked Ext.query functionality; the following does this for the second column of a grid ('.x-grid-col-0' would be the first column):

```
var qtyFields = Ext.query('.x-grid3-col-1 input', myGrid.getView().mainBody.dom);
var total = 0;
var qty;

for (var i=0, n=qtyFields.length; i<n; i++) {
    qty = parseFloat(qtyFields[i].value);
    total += isNaN(qty) ? 0 : qty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that doesn't rely on knowing classnames in the HTML is to get the information from the editing plugin.

```
var fields = grid.findPlugin('rowediting').editor.form.getFields();
var total = 0;

for (var i=0, n=fields.getCount(); i<n; i++) {
    var qty = parseFloat( fields.getAt(i).getValue() );
    total += isNaN(qty) ? 0 : qty;
}
```

Comment: This would only apply to ExtJS 4